# extract the sequence of a variable and separate it with "and" except for the last one

Tags: xquery, marklogic

0

I have a variale which returns a sequence of values. I want to print them in a function and they should be separated by "and" but the number of values of the sequence varies. it sometimes returns more or less values (I am using xquery) Let's say the variable is $var and it returns values like

INV_1
INV_2
INV_3
INV_4
i am trying to do the following :-

```
for $i in $loopvar
          return  
            if ((fn:exists($loopvar)) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 1)) 
            then $i || " and "
            else 
            if(fn:exists($loopvar) and (fn:count($loopvar) = 1)) 
            then " where " || $i
            else() ) ), " ")
```

I want the output in the following manner:-

```
INV_1 and INV_2 and INV_3 and INV_4
```

However I am getting it as :

```
INV_1 and INV_2 and
```

Can someone please correct my code?

Comment: Consider to post a minimal and complete sample to allow others to reproduce your result.

Comment: i have posted the complete information that is with me.

Comment: Your text mentions `$var`, your code uses two different variable names.

Comment: Please show an actual example of your $var or $loopvar.  If it's just a sequence of strings you can use string-join to do this (as was suggested in the similar question you posted recently).  Your loop here is trying to do more than you describe and it has several unnecessary conditions.  Please provide a reproduceable example with a real sequence.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sequence of values, you can use `string-join()` to produce the desired output.

This code:

```
let $values := ("INV_1", "INV_2", "INV_3", "INV_4")
return string-join($values, " and ")
```

produces:

> INV_1 and INV_2 and INV_3 and INV_4

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think using string-join as mentioned by Mads is much easier, but there is a trick you can use inside FLOWR statements to get hold of the current position that is worth mentioning. You can use the `at` clause of FLWOR statement to assign current position to a variable of choice. I am assigning it to $x in below code:

```
let $loopvar := ("INV_1", "INV_2", "INV_3", "INV_4")
let $count := fn:count($loopvar)
return
  if (fn:exists($loopvar)) then
    string-join((
      for $i at $x in $loopvar
      return (
        if ($x eq 1) then
          "where "
        else (),

        $i,
        
        if ($x lt $count) then
          " and "
        else
          " "
      )
    ), "")
  else ""
```

If I wrap Mads string-join in the same if fn:exists as mine, you really notice how much shorter it becomes:

```
let $loopvar := ("INV_1", "INV_2", "INV_3", "INV_4")
return
  if (fn:exists($loopvar)) then
    "where " || string-join($loopvar, " and ")
  else ""
```

HTH!